# Using highcharts with laravel blade with arrays

Tags: php, laravel, highcharts, laravel-blade

Hey guys I'm trying to attach a highchart in my blade template that looks like something like this

```
<body>
    ...
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 500px;height: 220px;"></div>
    <div id="test_length">Test Length: </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var myData = {!! json_encode($data['income_data']) !!};
            $('#test_length').append(myData.length); //This shows the number on 

            var chart = Highcharts.chart('chart_div', {
                credits: false,
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                yAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        formatter: function () {
                            return this.value;
                        }
                    },
                    gridLineWidth: 1,
                    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        animation: false
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    showInLegend: false,
                    data: myData,
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 5
                    }
                }]
            });
        });//end onload
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I did a `dd(json_encode($data['income_data']));` and the output looks like this

```
var myData output

"[["2012-11-30","10154.01"],["2012-12-31","10332.01"],["2013-01-31","10622.72"],["2013-02-28","10865.79"],["2013-03-31","10939.57"],["2013-04-30","10967.78"],["2013-05-31","11159.82"],["2013-06-30","10981.49"],["2013-07-31","11229.1"],["2013-08-31","11220.21"],["2013-09-30","11443.22"],["2013-10-31","11901.36"],["2013-11-30","12125.58"],["2013-12-31","12322.39"],["2014-01-31","12386.36"]]"
```

I suspect it's something to do with how I am passing my data to the highcharts library between the encoding where it's an array and not a JSON. Any help would be much appreciated as I have been trying to solve this for hours with no luck!

Comment: console errors. Format your data at back end with `intval()`  for value. if it is data time chart type use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` and multiply by 1000 to get (milliseconds) in `mysql` queries

Comment: Note that y-values for Highcharts should be numbers, not strings: `["2012-11-30","10154.01"]` -> `["2012-11-30", 10154.01]`. You can use `parseFloat()` to cast string to numbers.